# Save Bitmap image

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, save

I'm trying to modify an example of a machine vision library ( Common Vision Blox ). The example gets an image from the camera, converts it to bitmap format and shows to the user through a PictureBox.

What I want it is to save the data to a file, but I get a BMP all in black. I tried some variants but the result is the same.

If I save the image from the PictureBox, using PictureBox.SaveImage the result is the same if I

The code is this :

```
private Bitmap  _bm;
private bool    _bRequiresCopy;
private void cvImg_ImageUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // create a bitmap out of the image
  _bm = CvbImageToBitmap(cvImg.Image, out _bRequiresCopy);
  // and display it in the picture box

  //if (_bm != null) // Only this two lines in the original code 
  //    pictureBox.Image = _bm; 

  if (_bm != null)
  {          
      pictureBox.Image = _bm;

      // Tests to save

      _bm.Save("c:\\test.bmp"); // This don't work

      // The following don't work, but if add a button to the form and just place in the click 
      // event of the button it stores the image correctly
      pictureBox.Image.Save("c:\\test2.bmp"); 

      Bitmap TestBMP = new Bitmap(_bm);
      TestBMP.Save("c:\\test3.bmp"); // This don't work

  }
  // setup grab checkbox
  chkGrab.Enabled = cvImg.IsGrabber;
  chkGrab.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not a helpful description. Can you see the Image in the PictureBox? Also please always tag all your questions with the relevant platform: WPF, ASP, Winforms!

Comment: Yes, I can see the Image in the PictureBox. What I can't get it is the same image when I try to save it. If I call pictureBox.Image.Save("c:\\test2.bmp"); from another function i.e. from another button, it saves it correctly.

Comment: Sounds like a strange timing problem. Try to put the save in the Picturebox.LoadCompleted event!

Comment: After *pictureBox.Image = _bm;* write *pictureBox.refresh();*

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can save it in both ways.